# How to download an ISO file for Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, iso

I want to create an USB-stick with Ubuntu! I follow your example and download the start file. I get it as `ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-i386.iso.torrent`. When I start Rufus to create the USB stick, it will not find any ISO-file.

How do I get the ISO file for Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 14 is very old, the latest is 18.04. What version do you want?

Comment: A torrent is not the ISO file itself. It is a means of getting the ISO file if you have installed a torrent client such as Bittorrent, uTorrent or Transmission. If you haven't, use the real ISO download link that can be found elsewhere on the page.

Comment: I'm just to unpatient trying to get it down to start learning about Linux. I found it out my self and have now downloaded the file!

I installed BitTorrent and it downloaded it for me with the Torrent-file I got!

Comment: "14.05.5" ???? That can not be a correct number.

Comment: You're absolutely right 14.04.5 is the right number! ;-)

Comment: The following link may help you select a suitable iso file (version and flavour of Ubuntu) for your computer, [How to select the version and flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865)

Answer (score 2):

.torrent is a torrent file using that file you should be able to download .iso file of ubuntu and locate iso file on rufus and you will be able to create ubuntu on usb.  To download torrent file use any torrent client software like utorrent bittorrent or transmission etc.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering me. I hope some day be able to contribute my self in some way. some day.

Comment: If this answer helped then please mark as verified answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded a lot of Ubuntu .iso images over the years and every time I downloaded an Ubuntu .iso image it maxed out all the available capacity from my internet service provider, except for the single time I tried downloading the Ubuntu .iso file from a torrent mirror site which was a lot slower. Your mileage may vary, so if you don't want to waste your time waiting for the Ubuntu .iso to finish downloading you should try downloading it with both http and torrent, and cancel the download that is slower.

btw I always download all Ubuntu iso images from the [official Ubuntu website](https://www.ubuntu.com/download) and I use a download tool that has resume interrupted download functionality like *wget* has using `wget -c file.iso` or [GNU Wget for Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/faq.html#download), so I don't have to download the same bits twice.

```
-c
--continue
    Continue getting a partially-downloaded file. This is useful when
    you want to finish up a download started by a previous instance of
    wget or by another program.
```

An alternative to wget that works on all platforms (Windows/Mac/Linux) is the popular [DownloadThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) extension for Firefox. DownloadThemAll will help you select, queue, sort and run your downloads faster. It comes with advanced ways to select what links to download, and will remember your previous decisions so that you can queue more downloads with just one click. DownloadThemAll can also automatically or manually restart interrupted downloads in the same place where they were interrupted so you don't lose the part of the file that you already downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Ubuntu 18.04 then use this link http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/
Or you can try Ubuntu 16.04 
http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/
16.04 is also a LTS version and its 32bit flavour is also available