# About downloads using wget

Tags: downloads, ubuntu-gnome, wget

I was downloading a file using wget, about 700MBs were downloaded but some MBs were still left, and the terminal was still downloading the file, but eventually, my system turned off. What will happen to that 700MBs, where that MBs were gone, stored. From where can I get that half downloaded file, which part of my storage will be used by that file.
Can I continue to download that file, where It was stopped terminated?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)). Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download an ISO file for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031998/how-to-download-an-iso-file-for-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Half downloaded. You can start all over again.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: The guy behind this question already knows how to download with wget. he was just wondering if he needs to do it all over again after a sudden shutdown. simple question, simple answer.