# Bootable usb to use on another computer

Tags: boot

I'm trying to create a bootable usb to use on another computer. When I try to download the iso file it shows in downloads as having no bytes. It's the 18.04.4 file for desktops. Any advice?

Bit more info. It's only partially downloaded, nothing wrong with the internet connection to interrupt it.

So the only way around it I could find was to download the latest version 19:10,thats loaded on the computer,alls good it seems.Many thanks to all that responded.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I have seen the Ubuntu download take over an hour, It is 2 1/2 GB. Perhaps try Bit Torrent if your download is not completing.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please do not put new information about the question in your answer. [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1219005/edit) your question and add the new information about the question in the question. If you solve the problem then please provide a detailed answer to help others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download an ISO file for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031998/how-to-download-an-iso-file-for-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and try to download it using the next command:

```
cd ~/Downloads && wget -c http://mirrors.lug.mtu.edu/ubuntu-releases/18.04.4/ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso
```

`-c` option means ***continue***. If your file is partially downloaded, its downloading will be continued.

Comment: Brilliant,so far I should add,its downloading as we speak,will let you know if it completes or not.Thanks.

Comment: So the whole lot downloaded,thanks again,now to install on the other computer.Thanks again.

Comment: Ok. Nice to hear)

Comment: Back again,I've got the dreaded it would seem,EFI\BOOT\mmx.64.efi not found,can't seem to get around it in the bio,tis an acer laptop.

Comment: You could ask a new question explaining what happen there.